# N-triples IRI prefix jena

Tags: jena, prefix, n-triples, iri

I want to use prefix to represent this nt file:

```
<www.test.com/a/yan-dang-shan> <www.test.com/a/zhongwenming> <www.test.com/a/yan-dang-shan> .
<www.test.com/a/yan-dang-shan> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "a" .
<www.test.com/a/zhongwenming> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "b" .
<www.test.com/a/yan-dang-shan> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "c" .
```

What I write into a new nt file is:

```
@prefix sp: <www.test.com/a/> .
<sp:yan-dang-shan> <sp:zhongwenming> <sp:yan-dang-shan> .
<sp:yan-dang-shan> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "a" .
<sp:zhongwenming> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "b" .
<sp:yan-dang-shan> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "c" .
```

But when I use this to sparql in cmd:

```
SELECT ?x ?y ?z
WHERE
{ ?x ?y ?z . }
```

There is an error showed in cmd:

```
D:\>sparql --data=ceshi.nt --query=ceshi.rq
11:01:42 ERROR riot                 :: [line: 1, col: 1 ] Expected BNode or IRI:
 Got: [DIRECTIVE:prefix]
Failed to load data
```

I also tried this:

```
@prefix sp: <www.test.com/a/> .
sp:yan-dang-shan sp:zhongwenming sp:yan-dang-shan .
sp:yan-dang-shan <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "a" .
sp:zhongwenming <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "b" .
sp:yan-dang-shan <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "c" .
```

But it report the same error which I don't know how to fix it.

How should I revise to make it ok?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N-triples does not have prefixes.

Turtle has prefixes. Try putting your data in a file with extension ".ttl".

You can test your data with the command line tool `riot`.